# uploading image to the server returns no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to upload image to the server and I am getting a none-image object after upload using angularjs
here is my snippets

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
            // var filename = $scope.importIdeaFile.name;
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("photoUpdates"));
            console.log("formdata333.... "+formData);
            var formdata = new FormData();
            if(typeof $rootScope.userIdArg != 'undefined' && $rootScope.userIdArg != null && $rootScope.userIdArg !=''){
                formdata.append("userid",$rootScope.userIdArg);
                formdata.append('updatePhoto',new Blob([formData], {
                    type:"application/json"
                }));
                $http.post('/uploadIdeafile',formdata,{
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
                    .then(
                        function(response,status) {
                            alert("jarah123..."+response);
                        },
                        function(errResponse) {
                            alert(" Error while fetching User");
                        });
            }
        }
```

here is my html input tag

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file"
                                                       id="photoUpdates" ng-model="updatePhoto" size="60">
```

the format of what is uploaded is not image

Answer (score 0):

this approach solved my problem

```
$scope.saveFile = function() {
            var f = document.getElementById('photoUpdates').files[0],
                r = new FileReader();
            r.onloadend = function(e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                console.log(data);
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('userid', $rootScope.userIdArg);
                fd.append('updatePhoto', data);

                $http.post('/uploadIdeafile', fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
                    }
                })
                    .then(
                        function(response,status) {
                            alert("jarah123..."+response);
                        },
                        function(errResponse) {
                            alert(" Error while fetching User");
                        });
            };
            r.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
```

Comment: You specified that the content type of `updatePhoto` was "application/json", which is not a valid image type. Removing that type made the server guess as to the type of data, and it guessed correctly.